# Cant get ajax response to place nice with python code

Tags: javascript, python, django

**Question:**  For some reason I can't seem to figure out why my ajax call will not return a value for success if my wo_data query comes up empty. What I want to happen is if  I put a value into id_work_order and its not found in my db pop up an alert saying workorder was not found- otherwise if it is found return success which works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What happens is I get this if a workorder is not found in my browser console 
typeerror: data[0] is undefined

if it is found I get this 
success

Here is what my data looks like if the workorder is found in my response 
0: object

```
purch_order: "1" 
success: "success" 
part_rev: "A" 
part_number: "12345" 
work_o: "W0000001"
```

customer_name: "TEST"

if it isn't found I get nothing back in my response

here is my views.py

```
    def get_work(request): 
        if request.is_ajax(): 
            q = request.GET.get('workorder_id', '') 
            wo_data = Dim_work_order.objects.filter(base_id__icontains = q )[:1] 
            results = [] 
            for x in wo_data: 
                x_json = {} 
                if wo_data.exists(): 
                  x_json['success'] = 'success' 
                  x_json['work_o'] = x.base_id 
                  x_json['customer_name'] = x.name 
                  x_json['part_number'] = x.part_id 
                  x_json['part_rev'] = x.part_rev 
                  x_json['purch_order'] = x.customer_po_ref 
                  results.append(x_json) 
                else:   
                  x_json['success'] = 'workorder_not_found' 
                  results.append(x_json) 

            data = json.dumps(results) 
            mimetype = 'application/json' 
            return HttpResponse(data, mimetype) 

        else: 
            data = 'fail' 
            return render(request, 'app/sheet_form_create')
```

here is my workorder_ajax.js

```
        $(document).ready(function () { 

            //$('#id_work_order').click(function () { 
            //    getwork(); 
            //}); 

            $('#work_search').click(function () { 
                pop_other_fields(); 
            }); 



            //function getwork(){ 
            //    $('#id_work_order').autocomplete({ 
            //        source: "/sheet/sheet_form_create.html/get_work", 
            //        minLenght: 2, 
            //    });     
            //} 

            function pop_other_fields() { 
                var url = "/sheet/sheet_form_create.html/get_work?workorder_id=" + $('#id_work_order').val(); 
                var work_order = document.getElementById('id_work_order').value; 
                $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'GET', 
                    url: url, 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    data: '', 
                    success: function (data) { 

                        if (data[0].success = "success") { 
                            console.log(data[0].success); 
                            $('#id_customer_name').val(data[0].customer_name); 
                            $('#id_part_number').val(data[0].part_number); 
                            $('#id_part_revision').val(data[0].part_rev); 
                            $('#id_purchase_order').val(data[0].purch_order); 
                        } 
                        if (data.success = "workorder_not_found") { 
                            alert("workorder not found :(") 
                        } 
                    } 

                }); 

            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code here is never reached:

```
            else:   
              x_json['success'] = 'workorder_not_found' 
              results.append(x_json)
```

because if `if wo_data.exists():` is not true, then `for x in wo_data:` would never have any iterations in the first place.

Try:

```
def get_work(request): 
    if request.is_ajax(): 
        q = request.GET.get('workorder_id', '') 
        wo_data = Dim_work_order.objects.filter(base_id__icontains = q )[:1] 
        results = [] 
        if wo_data.exists(): 
            for x in wo_data: 
                x_json = {} 
                x_json['success'] = 'success' 
                x_json['work_o'] = x.base_id 
                x_json['customer_name'] = x.name 
                x_json['part_number'] = x.part_id 
                x_json['part_rev'] = x.part_rev 
                x_json['purch_order'] = x.customer_po_ref 
                results.append(x_json) 
        else:
            results.append({'success': 'workorder_not_found'}) 

        data = json.dumps(results) 
        mimetype = 'application/json' 
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked can't believe I missed that! @ben432rew